# UITextfield becomes clear while switching between the views

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have an array of  tableViewCell. each tableviewcell contains the textfield. and all of these are in the detail view. if I enter a value in the textfield and tap the back button, and when i return back to the detailview , the value in the textbox disappears.

please someone help me out for how to store the values.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have to save the value in `viewWillDisappear` and restore it in `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 0):

A cell gets recreated when it is shown again. If you have a value which the user changes you will need to store that in an array which the cells must read from when they are created in the cellForRowAtIndexpath delegate method.

You could use the uitextfield delegate method shouldChangeCharactersInRange to store the text that is written in an array which the cells can read from when assigning values to the text property of their textfields

Answer (score 0):

When you press the back button, the view that contained it is deallocated, so you will have to store that data somewhere outside of it. Two of the most common solutions to store shared data in the app are either storing it in the `App Delegate` or having a `Singleton` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the value of the textField in the `AppDelegate` method, and then store it back to the `UITableViewCell` by implementing the `viewWillAppear` method with `tableView reloadData`.

You need to carefully assign the value of that `UITableViewCell` so that the saved value corresponds to the particular tableViewCell. I would say that you use `tags` or may be subclass `UITableViewCell` an embed a `UITextField` inside of it. These are just options - you can logically implement this in your favorite way too !

:-)